# What other processes exist?

Tags: mathematical-statistics

I would like to know if there are other processes apart from stochastic and weiner.
I have looked for information and nothing

Comment: Don't worry about the number of processes. There are enough processes that you would not be able to finish studying all of them in your whole lifetime. Firstly, you may narrow down what type of processes you are interested in.

Answer (score 3):

I believe the processes you're talking about *are* stochastic processes. Stochastic just means random. A Weiner process is a type of stochastic process, as are Poisson processes, Markov processes, etc. You can find more examples using by searching the term stochastic process. The Wikipedia article is a good place to start as it lists a number of processes under *examples* and *further examples*. https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stochastic_process